# Google dataflow job which reads from Pubsub and writes to GCS is very slow (WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/GroupIntoShards) takes too long

Tags: java, java-8, apache-beam, google-dataflow

Currently we have a dataflow job which reads from pubsub and writes avro file using FileIO.writeDynamic to GCS and when we test with say 10000 events/sec , not able to process faster as WriteFiles/WriteShardedBundlesToTempFiles/GroupIntoShards is very slow. Below is the snippet we are using to write.
How can we improve

```
PCollection<Event> windowedWrites = input.apply("Global Window", Window.<Event>into(new GlobalWindows())
        .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(
            AfterFirst.of(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(50000),
                AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(DurationUtils
                    .parseDuration(windowDuration))))).discardingFiredPanes());

        return windowedWrites
                        .apply("WriteToAvroGCS", FileIO.<EventDestination, Five9Event>writeDynamic()
                                        .by(groupFn)
                                        .via(outputFn, Contextful.fn(
                                                        new SinkFn()))
                                        .withTempDirectory(avroTempDirectory)
                                        .withDestinationCoder(destinationCoder)
                                        .withNumShards(1).withNaming(namingFn));
```

We use custom filenaming say in the format, gs://tenantID.<>/eventname/dddd-mm-dd/<uniq_id-shardInder-of-numOfShards-pane-paneIndex.avro>

Comment: Is there any reason you are specifying 1 shard?

Comment: since the window logic specifies 50K and we use group by , don't want to arbitrarily generate more files

Comment: +1 Inigo's comment, shard of one would require all values for a window to be shuffled to a single thread.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is likely `withNumShards(1)` which forces everything to happen on one worker.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said, when using `withNumShards(1)` Dataflow/Beam cannot parallelize the writting, making it happen on the same worker. When the bundles are relatively high, this has a big impact on the performance of the pipeline. I made an example to demonstrate this:

I ran 3 pipelines that generate a lot of elements (~2gb), the three of them with 10 `n1-standard-1` workers but with 1 shard, 10 shards and 0 shards (Dataflow would choose the amount of shards). This is how they behave:

[image: Jobs]

We see a big difference between 0 or 10 Shard vs 1 Shard total time. If we go to the job with 1 shard, we see that only one worker was doing something (I disabled the autoscaling):

[image: CPU]

As Reza mentioned, this happens because all elements need to be shuffled into the same worker so it writes the 1 shard.

Note that my example is Batch, which has a different behavior than Streaming when it comes to threading, but the effect on pipeline performance is similar enough (in fact, in Streaming it may be even worst).

Here you have a Python code so you can test this yourself:

```
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    def long_string_generator():
        string = "Apache Beam is an open source, unified model for defining " \
                 "both batch and streaming data-parallel processing " \
                 "pipelines. Using one of the open source Beam SDKs, " \
                 "you build a program that defines the pipeline. The pipeline " \
                 "is then executed by one of Beam’s supported distributed " \
                 "processing back-ends, which include Apache Flink, Apache " \
                 "Spark, and Google Cloud Dataflow. "

        word_choice = random.sample(string.split(" "), 20)

        return " ".join(word_choice)

    def generate_elements(element, amount=1):
        return [(element, long_string_generator()) for _ in range(amount)]

    (p | Create(range(1500))
       | beam.FlatMap(generate_elements, amount=10000)
       | WriteToText(known_args.output, num_shards=known_args.shards))

    p.run()
```

Comment: So i did experiment with numOfShards.. i set it to 5 and hit OOM https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6923 Since too many files were written

Comment: Using more files should not cause OoMs, it would actually help to avoid them. If you are getting OoMs, try using machines with more memory per vCPU and set the shards to 0 so Beam determines the best way to spread it. Also, the JIRA you sent doesn't seem related and it's mark as fixed :D

Comment: with writeDymanic by(groupFn) , since we are grouping based in tenantId, event timestamp shouldn't that help with paralellism?